# Kornshell - How to print a file starting from a certain string to the end of the file?

Tags: unix, sed, ksh

I am currently using KSH.

There is a file with text in it, and say we're looking for a certain string inside that text.
*How would you print the contents of that file starting from that certain string to the end of file?*

I know that,

```
sed '/\(pattern\).*/{s//\1/; q;}'
```

will print the file starting from the beginning up until the string is found. I tried swapping it and I guess that does not work.

Thank you,
Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through sed,

```
sed -n '/pattern/,/&/p' file
```

If you want to print all the text which are next to the pattern then follow the below example,

```
$ cat ccc
foo
blah bar blah
gjhj
jjhk

$ sed -n '/ bar /,/&/p' ccc | sed -r 's/^.* (bar.*)$/\1/g'
bar blah
gjhj
jjhk
```

And through `awk`,

```
$ awk '/ bar / {sub (/^.*bar/,"bar"); f=1} f' ccc
bar blah
gjhj
jjhk
```

[I think you want this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24030856/kornshell-how-to-print-a-file-starting-from-a-certain-string-to-the-end-of-the/24030928?noredirect=1#comment37045461_24030928),

```
$ cal 6 2014 | awk 'NR==1{print} NR==2{print} / 20 / {sub (/^.*20/,"20"); f=1} f'
     June 2014        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30
```

If you want to properly arrange the date and day then try this,

```
$ cal 6 2014 | awk 'NR==1{print} NR==2{print} / 20 / {sub (/^.*20/,"               20"); f=1} f'
     June 2014        
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
               20 21  
22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I have used this code and it does work however it prints out that entire line. If the pattern starts in the middle of the line, how can I start printing from there?

Comment: Thank you! This is getting closer to what I am trying to print out. 

I am currently trying to print out a certain date in a the calendar using "cal" and "sed".

I am trying something like,

`cal 6 2014 | sed -n '/ 20 /,/&/p' ccc | sed -r 's/^.* (20.*)$/\1/g'`

But this is giving me a different output than what I am expecting. I am trying to get something like this

       `June 2014`
`Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa`
              `20 21`
`22 23 24 25 26 27 28`
`29 30`

P.S. Sorry I am new to using this format, I am trying to make this look neater

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I am looking for! But is there a way to have the 20 and 21 lined up under Fr and Sa? Starting at 20 was just an example that I thought of. I am actually using $day to replace the 20 so I can input any number I want.

Comment: How about this `$ cal 6 2014 | awk 'NR==1{print} NR==2{print} / 20 / {sub (/^.*20/,"               20"); f=1} f'`

Comment: I just tried the newest one you posted and that prints out the same thing as before, the 20 and 21 are under Su and Mo

Comment: Yes that works for the date 20, however I am going to use a $day (which is input by the user) and that will mess up the order of all other days .

Comment: I am replacing the 20 with '$day'

Answer (score 0):

You could use `awk`

```
awk '/pattern/ {f=1} f' file
```

When `pattern` is found, set flag `f` to true.
If flag `f` is true, print the line.

I do prefer this version compare to the range version, since its more flexible if you have other test to do to.

---

Another `awk` using range.

```
awk '/pattern/,0' file
```

Here the `end` pattern never becomes true, so it does not stop printing after `start` pattern is found.

---

Using range with `sed`

```
sed -n '/pattern/,$p' file
```

---

Print from `pattern` and rest of line.  My pattern is `yo`

```
cat file
Here is my data
What do you like
I like ice creem
```

```
awk -F "yo" 'NF>1 {f=1;print FS$2;next} f' file
you like
I like ice creem
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This prints out the entire line with the certain string in it. How can I start printing it from that string? Instead of starting from the beginning of the line.

Comment: `awk -F "pattern" 'NF>1 {f=1;print FS$2;next} f'` This should print `pattern` and the rest of that line, and all the next line.  See my updated post.